# jQuery get height in pixels

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following elements in a HTML page:

```
<body>
    <div style="height:100%; width:100%">
    <div style="height:100px;"></div>
    <div id="container" style="height:25%; width:50%">
    </div>
```

Now I would like to get the height in pixels of the div `container` using jQuery (or plain JavaScript).
How can I do it?

```
$('#container').height() // returns `0`
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In CSS, height as a percentage doesn't work unless the parent element also has height defined. And the parent's height won't work (if it's a percentage) unless its parent has height defined, and so on.

In this case, try adding this to your CSS:

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
```

**Update:** The other reason your code is returning `0` is because the DIV doesn't have any children (not even text nodes). If you added a child node, it would return the height of that child node, but it still wouldn't return the 25% value until you add an explicit height to all parents of elements that define height in percentages.

Answer (score 4):

With the code you provided, "0" is the correct answer. -- As mentioned in a comment below : Divs are block by default. The reason this resolves to "0" is because in this instance, the container that it is deriving the "%"s from, are 0. So you are essentially saying :  height = 0 * .25;

You need to either specify size of the div and its parent OR there need to be child nodes which grow the div's size naturally.

Then `$('#container').height()` will return a value larger than 0

Comment: this is wrong, `<div>` is by default a blocklevel element. Having 0 height has the reason, that it has neither children nor a parent with an explicitely set height.

Comment: This isn't true. DIVs are `display:block` by default.

Comment: Thats correct but due to the specific dom construction - the div is essentially a % of 0. I will amend my answer

Comment: setting `display:block;` won't do nothing. Just delete that whole block-element sentence, it's nonsense.

Comment: `$('#container').height()` isn't guaranteed to return an integer. See the Additional Notes section of http://api.jquery.com/height/

Answer (score 3):

You can do this `Height_String= new String($('#container').css('height'))`

the out put is  19px as string

or

You can do this `Height_Int = new Number (parseInt($(#container).css('height'), 10))`

the output is 19 as integer

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#container').css('height');
```

Comment: This is not what they are asking - that will return "25%"  --- NOT the actual dom element's height, but just it's CSS declaration

Answer (score 1):

The height is returned as 0 because the computed `#container` height is `0`. Assigning a `% height` to a div without any relative fixed height will be assigned to `0`.

See [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/rYd6k/) why it returns 0.

Answer (score 0):

If your block has visible height other than zero, then probably you call `jQuery.height()` before page is loaded. Wrap your call into `$(document).ready(function() {});`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    /* some actions */
    var h = $('#container').height(); // Height that you need.
});
```

Answer (score 0):

With simple JavaScript syntaxe it's works perfectly, but it's return the height in percent :

```
document.getElementById('container').style.height
```